# How to set canvas rectangle shadow on one side only?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, shadow, rectangles

I want to have a shadow on my rectangles bottom side only and don't have a shadow on the other 3 sides. To have a shadow I use this

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
ctx.shadowColor = "black";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 100, 80);
```

How to apply shadow only on one side of the rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

You can add shadowOffset property. For example:

```
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 25;
```

Comment: As it says in MDN web docs

offset - A float specifying the distance that shadows will be offset horizontally. Positive values are to the right, and negative to the left. The default value is 0 (no horizontal offset). Infinity and NaN values are ignored.

so how it would help? it only will move the shadow in horizontal